# android gradle copy task not work

Tags: android

I have a project structure as:

-main project 
--subject a

in my subject a `build.gradle` add copy task

```
 task makeDebugJar(type: Copy) {
   def dist = new File("livenessLib/build/outputs","jars")
   if (!dist.exists()) {
    dist.mkdir()
   }
   println "++++++debug MyLib task invoke ++++++: "
   def sourcedir = new File("build/intermediates/bundles/debug/")
   if (sourcedir.exists()) {
       from(sourcedir) {
         include('classes.jar')
       }
      into(dist)
      println "++++++Copy doaane ++++++: "
      rename('classes.jar', 'ZALiveness-debug.jar')
      println "++++++rename done ++++++: "
  }
 }
 makeDebugJar.dependsOn build
```

then build main project ,the log show every step invoke,and dir `jars` was created,but no jar in this dir .

anyone can help me resolve this problem ? thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

```
task copyFiles(type: Copy)

copyFiles {
    description = 'Copies html5 files from the common library...'
    from '../../www'
    into 'assets/www'
    include('**/*')
}
```

please see:

[How to run copy task with android studio into assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213236/how-to-run-copy-task-with-android-studio-into-assets-folder)