# How to copy resources files from other directory into Android project during sync or build?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

## The question

When you need to use resource files, such as images, in your Android project, typically you put them in the `res` directory (e.g. `res/drawable`), and the Android build process picks them up by default. But what if your resource files come from a directory outside of your Android project? How do you copy them into a folder like `res/drawable` during sync or build?

## What I have tried

I have a feeling that the solution is to write Gradle code, but I'm not sure how to do it. I tried the following code in my `app` module `build.gradle` file:

```
task copyResources(type: Copy) {
    from '../../../images'
    into 'res/drawable'
}
```

But it did not copy anything as far as I can tell. This is probably just my ignorance of how to use Gradle, and I could use some help.

I realize I could manually copy from `../../../images` to `res/drawable`, but let's say those files change often, and I want to get the current version automatically whenever I sync or maybe whenever I build. If this is possible, I would appreciate knowing how to do it. If it is not possible, I would like to know that as well.

Comment: "But it did not copy anything as far as I can tell" -- did you run the task? Tasks do not execute of their own accord. Either you execute them yourself, or you write a bit of additional Gradle code to add them to the existing series of tasks for a build.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532415/execute-task-before-android-gradle-build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to run copy task with android studio into assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213236/how-to-run-copy-task-with-android-studio-into-assets-folder)

---

Can do with adding

```
preBuild.dependsOn copyResources
```

after task copyResources(){...}
in your build.gradle.

But, it's not a good way for copying resources.

Comment: Thanks! This was it! But why do you say "it's not a good way for copying resources?" Would you recommend making a library like the other answer says, or is there some other reason you said that?

Comment: If lacks some image file (or renaming), editor may be confused with @drawable etc. Batch file is an alternative, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you don't want to do that. The reason is that it makes what would otherwise be a clean source control system confused by the copied files.

A better idea would be to build an Android library (AAR) housed in a separate project, then consume them by adding that AAR as a dependency to the parent project.